# Bookdown - Reference tag from another math environment broken

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

It seems i can't reference equations, lemas, etc when inside math.

In the following example the tag `eq:test` cant be referenced inside the `align`, but it works fine outside.

```
--- 
title: "Test"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: article
---

If

\begin{equation} 
  A = B
  (\#eq:test)
\end{equation}

then 

\begin{align*} 
     A \ &= B   &&, \text{ by } \@ref(eq:test)   \\  % this will not work
         &= C
\end{align*}

But here \@ref(eq:test) it works.
```

I want to know if this is currently not possible or i'm missing some special notation to make it work.

Comment: what's your output format? pdf or html?

Comment: I'm using both.

Answer (score 1):

Try with latex command `\label{}` and `\eqref{}`.

`\label`, `\eqref` works smoothly for pdf output as expected. For html output, we need to configure the Tex component of mathjax through the tex block as instructed [here](https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/equation-refs.html.html).

````
--- 
title: "Test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    documentclass: article
  bookdown::html_document2: default
---

```{=html}
<script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      tags: 'all'
    }
  };
  </script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
  
```

If

\begin{equation} 
  A = B \label{test-eq1}
\end{equation}

then 

\begin{align*} 
     A \ &= B   &&, \text{ by } \eqref{test-eq1} \\
         &= C
\end{align*}

But here \eqref{test-eq1} it works.
````

**pdf output**

---

[image: pdf output]

---

**html output**

[image: html output]

---

Comment: Nice one. But, correct me if i'm wrong, this solution is not general enough to deal with bookdown definitions, lemmas, etc. We can't use \label{...} for those environments. Moreover, the numbering for \label{...} is not synchronized with (\#...), we can use only one or the other, and if we use only \label{...} we lost the bookdown labeling system.

Comment: Yes, You are right :-(